# In Python and Scipy.sparse, how to assign the value of a matrix to a block of another larger matrix with a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

This is for Python 3.x or more specifically Scipy.sparse. I wish to write

```
import numpy as np, scipy.sparse as sp

A = sp.csc_matrix((4,3))
B = sp.csc_matrix(np.random.rand(2,1))
A[2:-1,0] = B
```

The last line does not work. I intend the last line to insert the matrix B into A as the block with row 3 to row 4 and column 0. What is the correct way to achieve this assignment without a loop?

Answer (score 2):

The setup

```
In [219]: from scipy import sparse                                                                     
In [220]: A = sparse.csr_matrix((4,3))                                                                 
In [221]: A                                                                                            
Out[221]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [222]: B = sparse.csr_matrix(np.random.rand(2,1))                                                   
In [223]: B                                                                                            
Out[223]: 
<2x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [224]: B.A                                                                                          
Out[224]: 
array([[0.04427272],
       [0.03421125]])
```

Your attempt, **WITH ERROR**

```
In [225]: A[2:-1, 0] = B                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-225-0dcce4b72635> in <module>
----> 1 A[2:-1, 0] = B

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py in __setitem__(self, key, x)
    111             if not ((broadcast_row or x.shape[0] == i.shape[0]) and
    112                     (broadcast_col or x.shape[1] == i.shape[1])):
--> 113                 raise ValueError('shape mismatch in assignment')
    114             if x.size == 0:
    115                 return

ValueError: shape mismatch in assignment
```

So let's focus on shapes:

```
In [226]: A[2:-1, 0].shape                                                                             
Out[226]: (1, 1)
In [227]: B.shape                                                                                      
Out[227]: (2, 1)
```

Well duh! we can't put a (2,1) into a (1,1) slot, even with dense arrays.

If we drop the -1, we get a 2 element slot:

```
In [230]: A.A[2:,0].shape                                                                              
Out[230]: (2,)
```

Now the assignment works - with a warning.

```
In [231]: A[2:, 0] = B                                                                                 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:118: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray_sparse(i, j, x)
In [232]: A                                                                                            
Out[232]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [233]: A.A                                                                                          
Out[233]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.04427272, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.03421125, 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

As a general rule, we don't make sparse matrices by assigning values to an existing 'empty' one.  We make a `csr` matrix with the `coo` styles of inputs - the row, col, data arrays.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So my idea was correct only that I indexed the matrix wrong. Could you please demonstrate the efficient assignment method?